# Removing unneeded information in filename using bash script

Tags: bash

I need to remove everything before and after a name in bash script, the following are examples

```
test_3123_123_testone-2.cpp
abc_3123_12312_a.cpp
johnchase_4123123123_123123123_johnc-1.cpp
```

I would need them simply change into

```
testone.cpp
a.cpp
johnc.cpp
```

But having trouble with regex and trying to get this setup properly, any advice would be great!

Comment: What if line doesn't end in `.cpp`?

Comment: Why isn't it `test.cpp` and `abc.cpp` and `johnchase.cpp`? or `123123123.cpp`? What are the rules? `Removing unneeded information in filename` What information is "unneeded"? How to classify an information as unneeded?

Comment: @KamilCuk I need it to be the text right before .cpp but ignoring any dashes(-2) if they exist behind it.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk It should keep the same file extension so .cpp it keeps .cpp and .py it keeps .py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the text right before .cpp but ignoring any dashes(-2) if they exist behind it.

Do exactly that. Write it from the end.

- "before .cpp" -> so `.cpp` must be last
- "ignoring any dashes" - so there is a dash(-2)

  - "if they exist behind it" - the dash is optional
- "the text" - so match the text.

```
var=test_3123_123_testone-2.cpp
[[ "$var" =~ ([^_-]*)(-[0-9]+)?.cpp$ ]]
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

If your filename is in a variable called `file`, then: `echo ${${file##*_}/-[0-9]*[.]/.}`.

Breaking that down, inside out:

- `${file$$*_}` remove everything from start of string to last `_`
- `${file/-[0-9]*[.]/.}` replace "dash number dot" with just a dot

This is not bullet-proof, but it covers the given cases.

```
$ for file in test_3123_123_testone-2.cpp abc_3123_12312_a.cpp johnchase_4123123123_123123123_johnc-1.cpp
do
  echo ${${file##*_}/-[0-9]*[.]/.}
done
testone.cpp
a.cpp
johnc.cpp
```